# SharedPreferences for Settings Screen

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to implement a settings screen to my app using SharedPreferences. When the app loads, it displays the default 'blank' text but when I hit the save button my app crashes. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

    Button saveButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save);
    EditText firstName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.firstName);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    firstName.setText(sharedPref.getString("firstName", "blank"));

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("firstName", view.findViewById(R.id.firstName).toString());
            editor.commit();

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Can you share error log?

Comment: @Nathan, Are you pretty much sure that your value is written in SharedPreference ?

Comment: copy and paste logcat here

Comment: fragment_settings.xml layout also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this change.

Replace

```
view.findViewById(R.id.firstName).toString()
```

with

```
firstName.getText().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
editor.putString("firstName", view.findViewById(R.id.firstName).getText().toString());
```